# Override method with shared_ptr Base type with shared_ptr Derived type

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding, smart-pointers, covariant-return-types

I am attempting to create an abstract method for cloning classes derived from base and returning them as a shared_ptr like so:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<BaseSymbol> clone() = 0;
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(const Derived& derived);
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> clone();
};
```

This is getting me a compilation error. I know this is possible to achieve this with normal pointers, so how can I get this to work with shared pointers?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115891/covariant-virtual-functions-and-smart-pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

covariance is only possible with pointer/reference.

For smart pointer, you have to "duplicate" the interface:

```
class Base {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Base> clone() const
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Base>(vclone());
    }

    virtual ~Base() = default;
protected:
    virtual BaseSymbol* vclone() const = 0;
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(const Derived& derived);

    std::shared_ptr<Derived> clone() const
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Derived>(vclone());
    }
protected:
    Derived* vclone() const override { return new Derived(*this); }
};
```

CRTP might help to avoid to rewrite the same pattern.

Comment: At least use `std::make_shared()`, and let the virtual method return a shared_ptr. Would be interesting to develop a feature allowing templates to opt-in to covariance...

Comment: @Deduplicator: That would require casting (with [`std::static_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)) :-/ from `std::shared_ptr<Base>` to `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` :-/

Comment: @Jarrod42: Under current rules, yes. But as they are structurally equivalent, one could change the rules. Or did you mean changing to `std::make_shared()`? Well, the one cast is worth it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: is it [your proposal](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92a3dcd677c5b36e)?

Comment: My comments were indeed about `std::make_shared`. allowing to mark types as covariant might be fine. or maybe just they are "custom" pointers.

Comment: Yes, you got it. Anyway, I think there is a proposal somewhere to allow a member-function (especially a template, and even better a generic lambda) to template the implicit argument. That would help here a bit too...